# How to change default wrapper location on Invoke Gradle Script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, gradlew

I have a project with different modules, I want to build the code from a specific module. I'm using "Invoke Gradle Script" in the build step on Jenkins.

By default, the Gradle plugin tries to locate the wrapper executable next to the build script. If it is not there it will look in the workspace root. What I try to do was changing the **Wrapper location**, to force the build of the correct module.

This is the code structure that I have.

```
|yurora
|
|---module
|---module
|---wos
|   |____src
|   |____gradle
|        |____wrapper 
|
|---module
|---module
```

This is the value that I have on **Wrapper location**

```
${workspace}/yurora/wos
```

But I get this error **FATAL: The Gradle wrapper has not been found in these directories: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTaskName/yurora/wos**.

If I change the value of **Wrapper location** to

```
${workspace}/wos
```

The code builds from the workspace root, and that is what I'm trying to avoid.

What should be the correct path on **Wrapper location**?

[Jenkins configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojQqp.png)

Comment: you might be over-complicating things. the wrapper does not belong into that module.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new git repo with the module that I wanted to build.

It ended up being easier for our time to do it like this, and everything worked out of the box.